# Are Quartz scheduler instances thread safe?

Tags: concurrency, thread-safety, quartz-scheduler

Can more than one thread safely call methods on an instance of [Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html) returned by the [StdSchedulerFactory](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html) concurrently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem so thought I'd look at the source code. Assuming you are using a standard configuration of Quartz (storing jobs and triggers in RAM instead of a persistent JobStore), then it appears that Quartz is thread safe.

Digging into the source, you will finally get to the RamJobStore, which stores all jobs and triggers in memory.

```
public void storeJobAndTrigger(SchedulingContext ctxt, JobDetail newJob,
        Trigger newTrigger) throws JobPersistenceException {
    storeJob(ctxt, newJob, false);
    storeTrigger(ctxt, newTrigger, false);
}
```

In each of the storeJob(..) and storeTrigger(..) methods, there are separate synchronized blocks with their own unique objects for storing jobs and triggers in a thread safe manner:

```
synchronized (jobLock) {
        if (!repl) {
            // get job group
            ...
        }
    }
```

And synchronizing a trigger:

```
synchronized (triggerLock) {
       ...

        synchronized (pausedTriggerGroups) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

So in short, it would appear that you can make thread safe calls to an instance of the Scheduler class